# Why do seaborn countplots and histplots display the same hexadecimal color differently?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, hex, seaborn

I'm trying to keep a singular color palette in my thesis, and I noticed that the blue of my histplots and the blue of my countplots are slightly different shades, even though I set them to the exact same hexadecimal value.

Is there a setting that I'm missing or do these different plots not just show the hexadecimal as given? I've tried playing around with the countplot saturation but it doesn't match the color. Ideally all of my histplots would have the same color as my countplots (and bar plots which use the countplot coloring too).

Below a minimum code example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20,10)}, font_scale=2)
plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.countplot(x="class", data=titanic, ax=ax[0], color='#5975a4')
sns.histplot(x="who", data=titanic, ax=ax[1], color='#5975a4')
```

It produces the following figure:

[image: Different Blues]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) has a saturation parameter (more saturation is more "real" color, less saturation is closer to grey). Seaborn uses saturation in bar plots to make the default colors look "smoother". The default saturation is `0.75`; it can be set to `1` to get the "true" color.

The `histplot` has an alpha parameter, making the color semi-transparent. The color gets mixed with the background, so it looks different depending on the background color. In this case, the `alpha` seems to default to `0.75`.  As that also has an effect similar to saturation, the `histplot` doesn't use saturation.  The transparency is especially useful when multiple histograms are drawn in the same subplot.

To get both in "real" color, set both the `saturation` of the `countplot` and the `alpha` of the `histplot` to 1:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize': (20, 10)}, font_scale=2)
plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.countplot(x="class", data=titanic, ax=ax[0], color='#5975a4', saturation=1)
sns.histplot(x="who", data=titanic, ax=ax[1], color='#5975a4', alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot and sns.countplot with "full" color]

PS: By default, a countplot uses only 80% of the width, while a histogram uses the full width. If desired, the histogram bars can be shrunk, e.g. `sns.histplot(..., shrink=0.8)`, to get the same width as the `countplot`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I found the saturation argument in the countplot docs but couldn't find anything for the histplot. I didn't look at the classes it inherited from though.

Do you know of a way of calculating which alpha would match the same shade of the default saturation of 0.75?

Comment: Transparency won't be exactly equal to desaturation. Apart from that, the final color will depend on the background. The best solution would be to use desaturation on the color value with alpha=1

Comment: Yeah, I played around with it for a bit but the transparancy ends up making it lighter (due to the light background) and the saturation makes it darker so its impossible to hit the default saturation of 0.75. I ended up just remaking all of my graphs with alpha = saturation = 1. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seaborn has a function to desaturate, so you can use: `sns.histplot(..., alpha=1, color=sns.desaturate('#5975a4', 0.75))`.  See also [seaborn's barplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) which remarks *"Large patches often look better with slightly desaturated colors, but set this to 1 if you want the plot colors to perfectly match the input color spec."*